# Что такое итераторы и зачем они нужны

Tags: итераторы, c++

Вот не могу понять основное предназначение итераторов . Погуглив , все равное не понял.

Пожалуйста объясните:

1. Что такое итератор?
2. Зачем он нужен?
3. Преимущества на указателем
4. Как его описать программно в коде? (то есть сделать свой итератор
   подобный библиотечным).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Смотрите. Пускай у вас есть контейнер. Неважно какой: `map`, `vector`, `set`. Он содержит набор элементов. И вы хотите сослаться не на весь контейнер, а на какое-то место в этом наборе элементов. Так чтобы от этого места можно было перейти вперёд/назад, и что-то в этом месте сделать: изменить элемент, вставить элемент, удалить элемент.

Как это сделать? Для массива вы в таких случаях пользуетесь индексом. `set` внутри является красно-чёрным деревом, так что вам понадобится ссылка на узел этого дерева. `unordered_map` использует хэш-таблицу, так что вам нужна пара из хэш-индекса и указателя на элемент внутри bucket'а.

Чтобы не приходилось писать алгоритмы, специфические для каждого контейнера, и были придуманы итераторы.

Итератор — структура данных, которая «указывает» на некоторый элемент контейнера, и (для некоторых контейнеров) умеет переходить к предыдущему/следующему элементу.

---

Если вы хотите реализовать итератор, помните, что существуют разные типы итераторов, в зависимости от операций, которые они предоставляют. Вот [список](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) возможных типов.

Если вы, например, хотите реализовать [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), вам придётся определить конструктор копирования, оператор присваивания, деструктор, операции `==`, `!=`, `*`, `->`, конструктор без аргументов, `++`, `--`, `+=`, `+` (2 шт.), `-=`, `-` (2 шт.), `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`. (Другие типы итераторов попроще.)

Кроме того, вам придётся специфицировать [`std::iterator_traits<It>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), где `It` — тип вашего итератора.

---

Вот вам [заготовка для собственного контейнера](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759622/276994) на SO. Немало, правда?

Comment: То есть итератор это как бы расширенный указатель , то есть мне допустим не надо знать как работает итератор для его использования , а использовать общепринятые правила . Хотя внутри для каждого определенного контейнера итератор может быть тем же указателем например как в массиве , а в других ситуациях элементы могут находится вразнобой в памяти , но итератор знает как добраться к определенному элементу . 
Правильно ?

Comment: @Alexandr Crospov: Совершенно верно!

Answer (score 9):

Итератор - это объект, который позволяет перемещаться (итерироваться) по элементам некоторой последовательности.
Использование таких объектов классифицируется как паттерн программирования *Итератор*.

Последовательность может быть как готовым набором объектов в памяти, так и состоять объектов которые создаются "на лету" при перемещении итератора (например читаются из файла).

В отличие от разнообразных последовательностей элементов (массивы, списки, файлы), итераторы имеют одинаковый интерфейс: получение текущего элемента, перемещение к следующему. Это позволяет писать более общие алгоритмы, которые работают с любыми итераторами, поддерживающими этот минимальный набор функций.

Итераторы стандартной библиотеки C++ повторяют интерфейс указателя. Это позволяет использовать указатели на элементы массива в качестве итераторов. При этом большинство алгоритмов используют только некоторый минимальный набор операций, например только перемещение вперед. Этот набор операций называется *категорией*, список всех категорий итераторов [перечислен тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479269/177684).

Варианты написания своего итератора есть [в ответах к этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485676/177684).