# Категории итераторов

Tags: c++, stl

Столкнулся с книжкой Л.Аммерааль STL. В начале этой книги столкнулся с категориями итераторов и мне стало непонятно что они значат? Объясните что собой представляют категории итераторов и в чем их отличия, а то есть категорий:

- входной
- выходной
- прямой
- двунаправленный
- произвольного доступа

Comment: Так в книге должно объясняться?

Comment: там в пример таблица дана без разъяснений

Comment: Тема довольно обширная и я не берусь давать здесь ответ. Могу рекомендовать правильную книгу, чтобы вопросов не осталось: [The C++ Standard Library](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/02/04/cpp_standard_lib_2nd.aspx)(ссылка на мой обзор). Это лучшая книга по стандартной библиотеке C++. В частности, категориям итераторов там посвящено 5 страниц.

Comment: спасибо что направляете в нужное русло

Comment: @perfect  "Столкнулся с книжкой Л.Аммерааль" - Надеюсь, ни вы, ни книжка не пострадали? Зимой особенно надо быть осторожным, так как дороги могут заледенеть!

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow спасибо за веселую нотку

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Категории итераторов определяют действия которые можно сделать с итератором.

Если итераторы использовали бы виртуальные функции, то категории итераторов были бы абстрактными интерфейсами, которые наследовались бы друг от друга:

```
интерфейс InputIterator { ... };
интерфейс OutputIterator { ... };
интерфейс ForwardIterator : InputIterator, OutputIterator { ... };
интерфейс BidirectionalIterator : ForwardIterator { ... };
интерфейс RandomAccessIterator : BidirectionalIterator { ... };
```

#### `InputIterator` (входной)

- Копирование, присваивание.
- Операции сравнения на равенство `==` и `!=`.
- Инкремент: `++iter` и `iter++`.
- Разыменование для чтения: `*iter` и `iter->m`, при этом запрещена запись: <strike>`*iter = value;`</strike>.

Пример входного итератора - это итератор чтения из потока: `std::istream_iterator`.

#### `OutputIterator` (выходной)

- Копирование, присваивание.
- Инкремент: `++iter` и `iter++`.
- Разыменование для записи: `*iter = value` и `*iter++ = value`, при этом запрещено чтение.

Пример выходного итератора - это итератор записи в поток: `std::ostream_iterator`.

#### `ForwardIterator` (прямой)

- Все операции `InputIterator` и `OutputIterator`.
- Требование *многопроходности*: если `i1 == i2`, то `++i1 == ++i2`, т.е. итератор можно копировать, и обходить им последовательность много раз.

Прямые итераторы - это итераторы односвязных списков, например `std::forward_list`.

#### `BidirectionalIterator` (двусторонний)

- Все операции `ForwardIterator`.
- Декремент: `--iter`, `iter--`, `*iter--`.

Пример: итераторы двусвязных списков (`std::list`), деревьев (`std::set`).

#### `RandomAccessIterator` (произвольного доступа)

- Все операции `BidirectionalIterator`.
- Операции сравнения: `i1 < i2`, `i1 > i2`, `i1 <= i2`, `i1 >= i2`.
- Сложение/вычитание с числом: `iter + n`, `iter += n`, `iter - n`, `iter -= n`.
- Разность итераторов: `i2 - i1`.
- Индексирование: `iter[n]`.

Пример: итераторы массивов (`std::vector`), указатели.