# Итераторы нужны лишь для удобства?

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы

Всем добра!

Решил на досуге почитать про библиотеку STL. Сам я начинающий разработчик с опытом написания небольших (~2000-5000 строк) desktop приложений для автоматизации процессов на предприятии в 1,5 года.

Собственно дошел до итераторов и встал вопрос, а в чем их, собственно, принципиальная надобность? Заменить указатели на массивы, чтобы повысить читаемость + безопасность?
В каких вообще случаях они применимы и обязательны?

Я в целом не пользовался указателями на массивы, кроме случаев, когда их надо передать в другие функции, но сортировку/выборку элементов/прч операции выполнял по "старому-доброму"

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       arr[i] = i;
    }
```

Собственно мне и интересно, насколько часто встречается использование итераторов и может мне имеет смысл потратить время чтобы научиться ими пользоваться здесь и сейчас?

Comment: Итератор - это по сути высокоуровневая абстрация, не привязанная к языку какому-то языку программирования. Например, в каком-то языке программирования может не быть указателей или ссылок на элемент, но может быть из коробки реализация итераторов. Ну и в целом есть типичные объекты, работа с которыми естественным образом реализуется через итераторы: например, построчное чтение файла, или какие-нибудь связные списки. Тот же файл легко читать по одной строке, но чтобы перейти на конкретную строку нужно каждый раз прочитать все предыдущие строки, либо сразу все строки прочитывать...

Comment: В целом, шаблоны проектирования - это просто набор типовых решений (буквально, шаблонов) для каких-то программистских задач. Это не значит, что нужно их пихать в каждую программу, это просто значит, что если какое-то типовое решение подходит под конкретную задачу, то его в ней можно применить, а не изобретать какой-то велосипед. Если вам достаточно просто итерации по индексу (на входе всегда 
 объект, имеющий такую возможность), то возможно итератор вам и не нужен.

Comment: @insolor, меня как раз и интересуют вопрос, а как понять, когда использовать итераторы. Тот же поток данных, к примеру, с текстового файла я считывал stream'ом, помещал в list и потом также перебором по индексу делал то что нужно. Для меня пока что эта технология выглядит не очевидной, как и сфера её применения. Тем более что есть неудобство, что при изменении, к примеру, размера массива, объявленный итератор становится нерабочим (это я из примеров вычитал).

Comment: Ну например если вам нужна только одна строка, а в файле их 100 тысяч, зачем их все загружать в список? Просто обрабатывайте построчно (поэлементно) итератором. `Тем более что есть неудобство, что при изменении, к примеру, размера массива, объявленный итератор становится нерабочим (это я из примеров вычитал).` - ну так не делайте так. Сначала обработайте итератором, потом уже модифицируйте исходный массив, если нужно.

Comment: Ну, очень грубо их можно рассматривать как индексы к массиву, только они куда более универсальны и не привязаны именно к массиву. Ну, например, у вас задача, где все время надо добавлять элементы в начало. Как это делать с массивом? Все время все элементы перекопировать? затратно. А какой-нибудь список — самое то, но к нему по индексу не обратишься, тоже затратно. Итератор — это способ обращения к элементам в некотором *контейнере*, который работу с контейнером прячет внутри себя. Как массив — более высокая абстракция по сравнению с переменными a0, a1, a2 и т.д. :) Ответ на вопрос: часто, да.

Comment: @insolor не совсем понял. Итераторы существуют внутри контейнеров, соответственно мне всё ещё надо перекладывать текст построчно из буфера (отделяя по разделителю, к примеру) в тот же массив. К его элементам я могу обращаться как итератором, так и по индексу и искать нужную строку.
@Harry т.е получается что итератор это возможность обратиться к элементам внутри любого контейнера, даже если контейнер не обладает ```operator[]``` и проводить сортировку/выборку и прч?

Comment: [Что такое итераторы и зачем они нужны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/270697)

Comment: @Maeshi, итераторы нужны если вы реализуете алгоритм (библиотеку) для набора элементов данных, который предполагаете использовать из других библиотек и о способе хранения данных в них понятия не имеете. Если вы делаете конкретную задачу (вместе со всей обработкой данных), то итераторы вам не нужны (лишняя сущность).

Comment: @wololo Спасибо за ссылку

Comment: @Maeshi `Итераторы существуют внутри контейнеров` - итераторы не существуют внутри контейнеров. Контейнеры могут реализовывать интерфейс итераторов, но не обязательно итератор должен быть привязан к какому-то реальному контейнеру в памяти (например, массиву). Итератор - это грубо говоря объект, из которого можно последовательно по одному получать его элементы. Никто не мешает, например, реализовать бесконечный итератор чего-то (допустим - чисел Фибоначчи), при этом реально выдаваемые элементы нигде храниться не будут, а будут просто генерироваться на лету.

Comment: В C++ предполагается, что у итератора должен быть конец, но в целом по идее шаблон проектирования "итератор" этого не требует. Ну и да, то что я выше описал - это скорее про шаблон проектирования "итератор", чем про конкретную реализацию в языке C++.

Comment: если целый набор классов использует разный способ доступа к элементам, то это приводит к неудобству использования шаблонных функций. Класс итератор как раз предлагает универсальный доступ, для того, чтобы шаблонная функция могла просто использовать много таких классов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указатели - подвид итераторов, поэтому вы их уже используете. ([Итератор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) - это любой тип, на котором работают определенные операторы - `*`, `++`, ...)

Но в отличие от указателей, у итератора `++`, `--` переключают его на соседние по смыслу элементы контейнера, а не на соседние блоки в памяти.

> В каких вообще случаях они применимы и обязательны?

Вопрос странный. Цикл по любому контейнеру (кроме `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::array`) придется делать через итераторы, потому что контейнер не умеет выдавать элементы по индексу.

Или допустим у вас есть `std::map`, и вы хотите в ней найти значение по ключу - `.find()` возвращает итератор. Хотите удалить значение? `.erase()` принимает итератор. Хотите посмотреть соседние значения? `++` и `--` на итераторе.